# Error Call to member function getwishlistItemId() on null

Tags: magento2

[image]<?php
/**

- @var $block \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Addto\Wishlist
  */
  ?>

```
$wishlistHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data');
$wishlistItem = $wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection()- 
 >getItemByColumnValue('item_id', $item->getId());
```

```
 <?php if($block->isWishListAllowed()): ?>
     <?php if($wishlistItem): ?>
    <a href="#" data-post='<?= $wishlistHelper->getRemoveParams($wishlistItem) ?>'>
        <?= __('Remove from Wish List') ?>
    </a>
        <?php else: ?>
           <a href="#" data-post='<?= $block->getWishlistParams() ?>'>
              <?= __('Add to Wish List') ?>
           </a>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: please try to give solution for this in this process only

Comment: Please update proper code to question and error screenshot as well that will help anyone to give you solution

Comment: code above is error pic below i don't know who pic screen shoot

Comment: Please add topsellers.phtml content to your question, that file causes your error. And could you edit your question to re-format your code and tell us the file path of these codes?